# Validating old method in control does not work correctly with empty value

Tags: laravel, validation, checkbox, laravel-9

In laravel 9, breeze form I use old method in controls like :

```
<x-input id="text" type="text" name="text" value="{{old('text') ? old('text') : $subscription->text }}" />
...
<input type="checkbox" @if (old('published') ? old('published') : $subscription->published) checked @endif
```

But it does not work correctly in case when in text input I leave empty text and I leave published field unchecked :

text input shows `$subscription->text(If it had some content from db)` and
published checkbox is checked (`If ($subscription->published)` was checked priorly from db)

How can it be fixed ?

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing a falsy check on the old values which will fail if they exist but are empty. Do  a stricter `old('text') !== null ? old('text') : ...` if you want to only show what's in the DB when the old value is not set at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox works differently then other inputs.

If checkbox is unchecked, it always get null in `old('published')`.

Now to fix that, we need 2 condition.

```
@php
    $checked = '';
    if (count($errors)) {
        $checked = old('published') ? "checked=''" : '';
    } elseif ($subscription->published) {
        $checked = "checked=''";
    }
@endphp
<input type="checkbox" {{ $checked }} .../>
```

First condition will check, is there any errors. If yes, then it will alway get value from `old('published')`.